# What's wrong in my code to find character frequency?

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

I'm trying to output all the letters and its frequency within the string but instead only `a` is appearing.  I thought my logic was correct but it looks like I'm missing something.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
public static void solution(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();

    int j = 0, i = 0, counter = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < c.length; i++) {
        if(c[i] != c[j]) {
            i++;
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The letter " + c[j] + " appears " + counter + " times");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "abaababcdelkm";
    solution(s);
}
```

output:

```
The letter a appears 1 times
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoeC I think OP is trying to output frequency of each letter and the code is not working as intended. I think the question is fair.

Comment: @sp92 Questions are mutable, and should be treated as such. If someone says something is wrong with the question, that is not a personal attack on you. You should use their feedback to [improve the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52932509/edit) and to inform the way you ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any preventive measure in your code that enables the code not to count same chracter in the feature steps. Here I just modified your code to make it work correctly. But you can compare it with other version I provided to prevent double counting.

```
public class Main {

public static void solution(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
            int j = 0, i = 0, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < c.length; j++) {

            if (c[i] == c[j]) {
                counter++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("The letter " + c[i] + " appears " + counter + " times");
        counter = 0;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "abaababcdelkm";
    solution(s);
}
}
```

Output:

```
The letter a appears 4 times
The letter b appears 3 times
The letter a appears 3 times
The letter a appears 2 times
The letter b appears 2 times
The letter a appears 1 times
The letter b appears 1 times
The letter c appears 1 times
The letter d appears 1 times
The letter e appears 1 times
The letter l appears 1 times
The letter k appears 1 times
The letter m appears 1 times
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please check the other version I provided below as an efficient version. You can also use TreeMap for this work.

Answer (score 3):

You are incrementing i twice each time you go through the loop. Because of this you are only testing every other character. Inside the loop use continue instead of i++.

```
public static void solution(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();

    int j = 0, i = 0, counter = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < c.length; i++) {
        if(c[i] != c[j]) {
            continue;
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The letter " + c[j] + " appears " + counter + " times");
}
```

Note that this code will tell you how many time the first character in the string appears in the rest of the string. Perhaps that is what you wanted but it is not clear from your question.

Comment: @sp92 Keep in mind that you can change your condition to test `if c[i] == c[j]` and only then increment your counter. The advance among the characters it's done by the increment of the for. Both codes are well

Answer (score 0):

I added Arraylist to keep the track of already counted chracters and each chracter will be printed only once

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void solution(String s) {
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        ArrayList<Character> arrayList;
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Character>();

        int j = 0, i = 0, counter = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (!arrayList.contains(c[i])) {
                arrayList.add(c[i]);
                for (j = i; j < c.length; j++) {

                    if (c[i] == c[j]) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("The letter " + c[i] + " appears " + counter + " times");
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "abaababcdelkm";
        solution(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The letter a appears 4 times
The letter b appears 3 times
The letter c appears 1 times
The letter d appears 1 times
The letter e appears 1 times
The letter l appears 1 times
The letter k appears 1 times
The letter m appears 1 times
```

Comment: Ramazan I see that you are new to stack overflow!  Thanks for answering the question. While it works, it is quite inefficient -- O(N*N) -- so I have a hard time upvoting your answer because others shouldn't copy it.  Can you reduce it to O(N) or O(NlogN)?  Thanks!

Comment: I told it as a comment that TreeMap could be used but I am not sure that it would be a familir way for @sp92.

Comment: I uploaded it here

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficint way with Maps

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abaababcdelkm";
        Map<Character,Integer> frequency = new TreeMap<Character,Integer>();


        for (int i = 0 ; i< s.length() ; i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);

            if (frequency.containsKey(ch)) {

                frequency.replace(ch, frequency.get(ch) + 1);

            }
            else {
                frequency.put(ch, 1);

            }

        }

        for (Map.Entry<Character,Integer> entry : frequency.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("The letter " + entry.getKey() + " appears " + entry.getValue() + " times");


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contributions!  We should probably distinguish your two solutions because this one will _probably_ be better for longer strings, but the accepted answer will be better for short strings.  How long is long?  Hard to say without measuring it.